# Convert column of arrays to table of K,V pairs in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have a presto with a column of string arrays I would like to convert to a table of each element in the array mapped to its number of occurrences.

A, B, C, D, E, F are all strings

```
set
---------
[A,B,C,D]
[A,C,E,F]


string|count
-------------
A      2
B      1
C      2 
D      1
E      1
F      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use [`unnest()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) and aggregate:

```
select char, count(*)
from t cross join
     unnest(t.set) as u(char)
group by char
```

Comment: Does this work if A, B, etc.. are strings and not chars?

Comment: @lui . . . I'm not sure if I understand the difference between "strings" and "chars".  But this should work for any reasonable data type.